# How to implement android wheel?

Tags: android

Is there a good widget to make an android wheel picker ? I found this lib https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker but I need some more methods

Comment: You can use Custom Dialog Picker with custom theme for more info follow this link

Answer (score 1):

You can try WheelView

```
<com.wangjie.wheelview.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/main_wv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

https://github.com/wangjiegulu/WheelView

https://github.com/DavidPizarro/PickerUI

https://github.com/venshine/WheelView

[image]

Comment: Can this auto scroll ?  I want to have like a slot machine , press a buttotn and start rolling